# mongodb gathering all records from different collections

Tags: php, mongodb, collections

i am trying to grab all records from mongodb using php. 
i have two collections. question is, in practice will i be able to make a simple sentence such as for each record on the database? :

> ie: john[from names collection] lives in city[from city collection] who
>   drives[from car collection].

Is this the correct coding for the above? I am still a newbie trying to learn step by step

```
 <?php foreach ($details as $doc) {
echo $doc['name'] . ' lives in'; } 
foreach ($place as $city) {
echo $city['name'] . ' who drives a '; }
foreach ($car as $ride) {
echo $ride['name']; 
echo '<br>'} ?>
```

your thoughts are welcome

Comment: I think that the better approach would be to have a single collection say users and have name, city and car for a every user populated in it. { name: 'john', city: 'Paris', car: 'BMW' }....

Comment: but how would it perform compared to the above example. is the coding correct though, were i to use different collections?

Comment: The PHP code should perform if you have the fields $details, $place, $car populated correctly. However, I believe that these should go in a single collection. If you could provide the samples of the 3 collections then it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect this to be used with, say, a `user_id` of sorts. Doing a full table scan of this would be a really bad idea.

Here is what you can do providing you have the `user_id`:

```
$users = $mongo->users->find(['_id' => ['$in' => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]]);

// Set some variables which will help us perform the detail queries
$cityIds = [];
$rideIds = [];
$userResults = [];
$cityResults = [];
$rideResults = [];

// Iterate through our users.
foreach($users as $_id => $user){

    // We store the MongoId for use in queries
    $cityIds[] = $user['city_id'];
    $rideIds[] = $user['ride_id'];

    // We then store the user result itself so we don't 
    // Do this query multiple times.
    $userResults[$_id] = $user;
}

// Now, let's get our first details.
$cityResults = iterator_to_array(
    $mongo->cities->find(['_id' => ['$in' => $cityIds]])
);

// And our ride details
$rideResults = iterator_to_array(
    $mongo->rides->find(['_id' => ['$in' => $rideIds]])
);

// Now let's loop and echo
foreach($userResults as $k => $user){
    echo $user['name'] . 
        ' lives in ' . 
        $cityResults[$user['city_id']]['name'] . 
        ' who drives a ' . 
        $rideResults[$user['ride_id']]['name'];
}
```

Something like that would do the trick.

Here I assume that your user schema has a `city` and `ride` ID in it respectively and that the two ID fields store an `ObjectId` (`_id`) of a `city` and `ride` row; this seems to be the most logical schema.

Comment: thank you so much for coding in such a way that i can understand. especially grateful for the comments on the code.
Kind Regards

Comment: should the objectid for a particular user be the same on the other collections then setting the id once would be enough right?

Comment: @user3108623 if that is the way round your relations work then yes

Comment: one more question: if it were to search the whole collection for users would the `find()` suffice?

Comment: @user3108623 it should do yes

Comment: i am trying to gather data using the same user id from the different collections, however i get errors such as "undefined index". i have tried to set the city_id and ride_id, it shows errors nonetheless.

Comment: @user3108623 that measn that some of your users do not have those fields set as such you should be using isset() to check that they do, also you have an error in your code here: `foreach($userResults as $k => $username){` if you see my code I use `user`

Comment: on the `$cityResults[$user['city_id']]['name']` it returned illegal offset type, so i changed it to `$cityResults($user['city_id'])['name']` now it returns "Function name must be a string". what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Nest the for loops inside of each other.

```
<?php 

foreach ($details as $doc) {
 foreach ($place as $city) {
  foreach ($car as $ride) {
   echo $doc['name'] . ' lives in '.$city['name'].' who drives a '.$ride['name'].'<br/>'; 
}
 }
  }
?>
```

Thats how i do it when im trying to access data in multiple collections to form the output

Comment: That will pull results out n ^ 3 times which is...terrible

Comment: the code above works to an extent however as  sammaye mention, it retrieves everything x3. how would one simply be able to pull results once.

Comment: @user3108623 iterator_to_array each query then use php arrays to match them up

Comment: tried to do the iterator to array, however not much success? can you show me where would you put the code for the iteration et al?